# Cordova localStorage removeItem doesn't work immediatelly

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, local-storage

I am using window.localStorage in a Cordova app. I add item like this: `window.localStorage.setItem("auth", "SOMETHING")`, when user signs in. I then at some point call: `window.localStorage.removeItem("auth")`, when user signs out.

If I kill the app on Android within 1-2 seconds after sign out, the local storage item is not removed and is available when the application is restarted. However, if I wait around 10 seconds before killing the app, the removal is persisted, i.e. the item is not available after app restart.

Any ideas how to make removeItem() work immediately? Thanks!

Comment: Are you testing on a device ? (just in case it would be a simulator bug)

Comment: Yes, on the device. I also show alert(1) and alert(2) before and after I call removeItem(), to make sure there were no errors generated. Then, if I close the app within 1-2 seconds after alert(2), then when I restart it, the data is still there. Weird. Must be some "optimisation" that only writes the data to the device every X seconds. I wonder if there is a way to force it, specifically on Android (I guess the webview in Cordova is Chrome). Can't find anything on the Internet.